# JQuery - How can I manipulate tabs

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

How can I manipulate the jquery tab, for example when a submit form is triggered in tab2 then the page selected tab should be the tab2 not the tab1?

Comment: What kind of tabs? Are you using a tabs plugin? What have you tried? Please be more specific and show some effort.

Comment: it is specified by the tag, and in the content I also said which tab I use. Again FYI its jquery tab. Should I specify more Sir?:)

Comment: Yes, you should have specified [tag:jquery-ui-tabs] as at least a tag. There are countless "jQuery tab" plugins out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery UI tabs, check their `selected` option. [Docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).

So, in your `php` code you must set this option on your tabs, like so:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({ selected: 2}); // 2nd tab will be default selected
```

or so, after tabs creating (if creation code in separate file, for example):

```
$('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected', 2);
```

Also, you can emulate clicking by tab using:

```
$('#tabs a[href=#tab_id]').click(); // where `tab_id` is tab content identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is just for UI display, just simply trigger the tab click action programmatically like this `$("tab2Selector").click();`